# Euclidean distance in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, distance

I have two 3000x3 vectors and I'd like to compute 1-to-1 Euclidean distance between them. For example, vec1 is

```
1 1 1  
2 2 2    
3 3 3  
4 4 4  
...
```

The vec2 is

```
2 2 2
3 3 3  
4 4 4  
5 5 5  
...
```

I'd like to get the results as

```
1.73205081  
1.73205081
1.73205081
1.73205081
...
```

I tried`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(vec1,vec2)`, and it returns a 3000x3000 matrix whereas I only need the main diagonal. I also tried `np.sqrt(np.sum((vec1-vec2)**2 for vec1,vec2 in zip(vec1,vec2)))` and it didn't work for my purpose. Is there any way to compute the distances please? I'd appreciate any comments.

Comment: Are you storing your vectors in a list?

Comment: Yes, in 2 different files. The following posts answered my question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cdist` gives you back a 3000 x 3000 array because it computes the distance between every *pair* of row vectors in your two input arrays.

To compute only the distances between corresponding row indices, you could use [`np.linalg.norm`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html):

```
a = np.repeat((np.arange(3000) + 1)[:, None], 3, 1)
b = a + 1

dist = np.linalg.norm(a - b, axis=1)
```

Or using standard vectorized array operations:

```
dist = np.sqrt(((a - b) ** 2).sum(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way that works. It still utilizes the `np.linalg.norm` function but it processes the data, if that is something you needed.

```
import numpy as np
vec1='''1 1 1
    2 2 2
    3 3 3
    4 4 4'''
vec2='''2 2 2
    3 3 3
    4 4 4
    5 5 5'''

process_vec1 = np.array([])
process_vec2 = np.array([])

for line in vec1:
    process_vec1 = np.append( process_vec1, map(float,line.split()) )
for line in vec2:
    process_vec2 = np.append( process_vec2, map(float,line.split()) )

process_vec1 = process_vec1.reshape( (len(process_vec1)/3, 3) )
process_vec2 = process_vec2.reshape( (len(process_vec2)/3, 3) )

dist = np.linalg.norm( process_vec1 - process_vec2 , axis = 1 )

print dist
```

`[1.7320508075688772 1.7320508075688772 1.7320508075688772 1.7320508075688772]`

Comment: In general it's going to be a lot faster to use vectorization to process multiple rows (e.g. `np.linalg.norm(process_vec1 - process_vec2, axis=1)`) rather than using `map`, which implicitly iterates over the rows in Python rather than C.